# Erro ao gerar Token de confirmãção de E-mail no Asp.MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-azure, token

Fiz um aplicação que uso o sistema de login do Asp.Net MVC. Eu testei localmente o envio do token para confirmação de e-mail e funciona perfeitamente, mas quando subi para o Azure no WebApp na conta gratuita para afim de teste sempre me aparece este erro quando vou registar um novo usuário.

> The data protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating.

O usuário é registrado mas falha no envio ou geramento do  mesmo, percebi que o erro sempre ocorre nessa linha que fica na classe AccountController, método Register:

```
var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
```

Comment: Pelo contexto da mensagem, você está tentando enviar um e-mail para um usuário que "não existe" (pois ainda não está logado, daí o sistema não sabe para quem enviar).

Comment: @UilqueMessias, apontou bem o erro, mas, para tirar toda a dúvida poste o código por favor Robz para que tenhamos possibilidades de apontar os problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é o seguinte: Vc está agora desenvolvendo para nuvem, então você não pode criar um provedor de dados a cada requição, e sim manter apenas um por aplicação.

[Veja aqui essa resposta em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30676983/2520523).

Para contornar isso, você deve criar um únido *DataProvider* no iniciar de sua aplicação.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    internal static IDataProtectionProvider DataProtectionProvider { get; private set; }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();
        // other stuff.
    }
}
```

A partir daí, deve-se sempre utilizar o mesmo *DataProvider* em todos os momentos.

```
public class UserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public UserManager() : base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new MyDbContext()))
    {
        var dataProtectionProvider = Startup.DataProtectionProvider;
        this.UserTokenProvider = 
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));

        // do other configuration
    }
}
```

Tanto na geração de tokens de login, quanto nos tokes para trocas e recuperação de senhas.